# Can anyone tell me why this search parition for quicksort works?

Tags: algorithms

```
private static < T extends Comparable < ?super T >> int partition(T[] a, int first, int last) {
  int mid = (first + last) / 2;
  sortFirstMiddleLast(a, first, mid, last);

  swap(a, mid, last - 1);
  int pivotIndex = last - 1;
  T pivot = a[pivotIndex];
 
  int indexFromLeft = first + 1;
  int indexFromRight = last - 2;
  boolean done = false;
  while (!done) {
   
    while (a[indexFromLeft].compareTo(pivot) < 0)
    indexFromLeft++;

    while (a[indexFromRight].compareTo(pivot) > 0)
    indexFromRight--;
  
    if (indexFromLeft < indexFromRight) {
      swap(a, indexFromLeft, indexFromRight);
      indexFromLeft++;
      indexFromRight--;
    }
    else done = true;
  } 
  swap(a, pivotIndex, indexFromLeft);
  pivotIndex = indexFromLeft;
 
  return pivotIndex;
}
```

It doesn't seem to touch the first or last elements

Comment: Prove (CS!) that it *does* work: you may find someone willing to scrutinise uncommented code to pinpoint *why*.

Answer (score 1):

`sortFirstMiddleLast()` sorts the first, middle, and last elements in-place. Once that's done, there's no need to consider the first or last value because (if the middle value is used as the pivot) they're known to be correctly partitioned.